# Can't find the right gigabyte motherboard to update the bios

Tags: motherboard

My friend has a gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2 and we need to update the BIOS, but when we look it up there are three revisions of it, but non of them match in color of the motherboard, his is brown, but non of the revisions are. What is the right one?

Comment: You mention the revisions don't match your friend's motherboard, but don't mention, which revision they actually have.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, all the chip sets and features are the same, only the processor that comes or is recommended changes

I believe that you can do any of them, but I'm not 100% sure.

Usually the revision is near the model on the Motherboard try looking there first